# Hibernate 4.1.x throws exception - Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, hibernate

We have an app running on tomcat using mysql. Recently, we upgraded hibernate 4.1.7. Time to time, very intermittently, I get communication link failure.

```
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Communications link failure

Last packet sent to the server was 15667584 ms ago.


at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2870) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3381) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:753) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:741) ~[hibernate-core-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at common.HibernateUtil.saveObjectNonTransactional(HibernateUtil.java:123) ~[classes/:?]
```

We looked at mysql side and confirmed we have enough available connections. This is the partial hibernate config

```
<!--property name="dialect">net.sf.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property-->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <!--c3p0 connection pool - can be used for deployment and schema generation -->

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://10.222.8.60:3306/pasi_v1_5</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">7200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1800</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>!-->
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what is max c3p0 max pool size and mysql timeout?

Comment: MySQL has a `wait_timeout` setting which will close the connections idle over a period of time. If your `idle_test_period` and `timeout` are greater than MySQL `wait_timeout` (28800 seconds by default), your unused connections will have chance to be reset by MySQL server before tested or timed out by C3p0.

Comment: Good point, like you said, we don't have wait_timeout set in the mysql. Therefore, it will use 28800 and c3p0 idle test period is 1800 and timeout is 7200 (shown above). Both are smaller than 28800

Comment: Communication link failure generally leads to when mysql server closed the connection but application pool still has that connection in pool and tries to use it..so check mysql server config

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because of mysql wait_timeout was smaller than Hibernate idle time out. Therefore mysql closes the connection early and hibernate was not able to reference the connection to close from its side.